# published web site display error

Tags: html, asp.net, web-config

I have created an asp.net webpage and have uploaded it onto a webserver. However when I try to view the page remotely, I get errors about the customerror tag in the web.config file. The page works locally with no errors or warnings. Also if I upload the page as a .html file, I can view it fine remotely. I have seen a lot of other people with this error, but the 'solutions' just say to change the customErrors tag to 'Off', which I have done and does not work, do you know is there an issue with the webserver or what could be the problem here?

Here is my Web.config file

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.10.0" newVersion="2.6.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.10.0" newVersion="2.6.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.1.28.0" newVersion="1.1.28.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: {E07B23BB-5CBC-4013-A9FB-9FC9D224B101}-->
```

My website display error like

Runtime Error

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>


Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

How can solve this issue?

Comment: You should have only one `<system.web>` in your config file.

Comment: yes @Div is right.Add  `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` inside `<system.web>`.Then only you will get the exact error.